# Nested Embedding in Kundera

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, kundera, nosql

I have 2 Embeddable objects and 1 Entity object. I want to use first Embeddable object inside another. Currently its not working for me. Below is the code

Class 1

```
@Embeddable
public class Object1{
    public Object1{
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Class 2

```
    @Embeddable
    public class Object2{
        public Object2{
        }

        @Column(name = "name")
        String name;

    @Embedded
    @Column(name = "object1")
        Object1 object1;

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

    public Object1 getObject1(){
            return object1;
        }

        public void setObject1(Object1 object1){
            this.object1 = object1;
        }
    }
```

Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xxx", schema = "yyy@zzz")
public void EC{

    public EC(){
    }

    @Embedded
    @Column(name = "object2")
    Object2 object2;

    public Object2 getObject2(){
        return object2;
    }

    public void setObject2(Object2 object2){
        this.object2 = object2;
    }
}
```

When I run this program, **only name of Object2** is getting saved but not the embedded **Object1**

Is this structure is possible in Kundera? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

allowed only for Cassandra's composite partition key

-Vivek

Comment: Are you sure it is not available for MongoDb?

Comment: Not yet supported by Kundera for mongo db.